# Why can't I use websocket in a function

Tags: python, websocket

When I try using websocket like this

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(f"wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/{symbol}@aggTrade",on_message=on_message,on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

it works fine but for some reason I want to use it like this

```
def func(symbol):
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(f"wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/{symbol}@aggTrade",on_message=on_message,on_close=on_close)
    ws.run_forever()
func("btcusdt")
```

but it's not working why can't I use websocket in func how can I do that

Comment: "it's not working" is not a clear enough description of your problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: It's literally doing nothing just like I didn't even call the function just waits @ThierryLathuille

Answer (score 0):

This (minor change to OP's code due to SSL issue) works perfectly on Python 3.9.9

```
import websocket
import ssl


def on_msg(_, msg):
    print(msg)


def on_err(_, err):
    print(err)


def func(symbol):
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        f"wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/{symbol}@aggTrade", on_message=on_msg, on_error=on_err)
    ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func('btcusdt')
```

Comment: Your answer would probably have more value if you could add an explanation of why this is necessary to run the OP's code in a function vs at top level.

Comment: It's not *necessary*. My answer merely demonstrates that with the Python version I'm using this does work whereas the OP seems to have a problem when running a WebSocketApp within a function

Comment: Let me correct somethings first of all my question was missing websocket can be used in a function it was working and I didn't understand that at the first 
second thing is when I put a timer in on_message func it works when websocket code are not in a function but when I try It with websocket codes are in a function its not working at all @DarkKnight

Comment: @WebsocketUser Maybe you should post a representative sample of your code that does **not** work

Comment: I have Fixed my problems my self thank you for all your helps

Comment: @WebsocketUser Could you share your solution?